# What's wrong with my python code?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm a beginner programmer and I've been completing  zedshaw's `Learn Python The Hard Way` course, however in exercise 26 we are given a flawed code so we can debug it. Although the code was written using Python 2.x I've been re-writing them in Python 3 so I could learn it.

It raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omar/PycharmProjects/Python_The_Hardway/ex26_Quiz.py", line 76, in <module>
    print("We'd have {} beans, {} jars, and {} crates".format(secret_formula(start_point)))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Here's my code: [link](http://pastebin.com/bK9Ng6Vm)

Original code: [link](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/exercise26.txt) (This is the exercise file)

So my  questions are:

- Why does it finish with exit code 1?
- Why doesn't it continue executing the code?
- How can I rewrite it using Python 3?

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

The `secret_formula` method returns a tuple, so you're essentially calling `.format()` with a single argument - the tuple.  Try putting a `*` in front of `secret_formula()`:

```
print("We'd have {} beans, {} jars, and {} crates".format(*secret_formula(start_point)))
```

That'll treat the tuple as separate arguments, and *should* fix it.

Comment: Wow!, Thanks Kevin! I spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it finish with exit code 1?

Because you get an error.

> Why doesn't it continue executing the code?

Because you get an error.

> How can I rewrite it using Python 3?

The original Python 2 code looks like this:

```
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crabapples." % secret_formula(start_pont
```

The Python 3 version of that is:

```
print("We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crabapples." % secret_formula(start_pont)
```

I added parenthesis around what is to be printed, since the `print`-statement is now a `print()` function.

Now, this code is of course broken, because it lacks a closing parenthesis, and `start_point` is miss-spelled. So it should really be:

```
print("We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crabapples." % secret_formula(start_point))
```

If you want to move over to the new `.format()` formatting instead of the old `%` formatting, then it would look like this:

```
print("We'd have {:d} beans, {:d} jars, and {:d} crabapples.".format(*secret_formula(start_point))
```

But that's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Lennart, they are really useful for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is given below

```
def break_words(stuff):
        """This function will break up words for us."""
        words = stuff.split(' ')
        return words

    def sort_words(words):
        """Sorts the words."""
        return sorted(words)

    def print_first_word(words):
        """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
        word = words.pop(0)
        print word

    def print_last_word(words):
        """Prints the last word after popping it off."""
        word = words.pop(-1)
        print word

    def sort_sentence(sentence):
        """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
        words = break_words(sentence)
        return sort_words(words)

    def print_first_and_last(sentence):
        """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
        words = break_words(sentence)
        print_first_word(words)
        print_last_word(words)

    def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
        """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
        words = sort_sentence(sentence)
        print_first_word(words)
        print_last_word(words)


    print "Let's practice everything."
    print 'You\'d need to know \'bout escapes with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs.'

    poem = """
    \tThe lovely world
    with logic so firmly planted
    cannot discern \n the needs of love
    nor comprehend passion from intuition
    and requires an explantion
    \n\t\twhere there is none.
    """


    print "--------------"
    print poem
    print "--------------"

    five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 5
    print "This should be five: %s" % five

    def secret_formula(started):
        jelly_beans = started * 500
        jars = jelly_beans / 1000
        crates = jars / 100
        return jelly_beans, jars, crates


    start_point = 10000
    beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)

    print "With a starting point of: %d" % start_point
    print "We'd have %d jeans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (beans, jars, crates)

    start_point = start_point / 10

    print "We can also do that this way:"
    print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crabapples." % secret_formula(start_point)


    sentence = "All god\tthings come to those who weight."

    #python_exercise.break_words(sentence)
    #words = python_exercise.break_words(sentence)
    #python_exercise.sort_words(words)
    #sorted_words = python_exercise.sort_words(words)

    #print_first_word(words)
    #print_last_word(words)
    #print_first_word(sorted_words)
    #print_last_word(sorted_words)
    #sorted_words = python_exercise.sort_sentence(sentence)
    #print sorted_words

    #print_first_and_last(sentence)

    #print_first_a_last_sorted(sentence)
```